# jupyter notebook instance on port 8889 appears broken

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When my jupyter notebook (version 1.0.0) runs my Mac on port 8889, the instance appears broken and I'm unable to load any of the notebooks, see screenshot below

[image]

[image]

Any ideas of why this could be happening? It works on any of the other ports I've tried: 8888, 8891, etc

I've got the conda installation. These are the details:

[image]

Comment: It runs on 8889 for me, so I doubt it's a problem with notebook. My assumptions would be either theres something else already running on that port. Maybe another hanging instance or some accompanying service, like jupyter lab service if you have that idk. Anyway, have you tried turning it (pc) off an on? Also try going to "localhost:8889" itself, maybe something interesting will open.

Comment: @IcedLance yes, I have tried restarting it already and also checking there port is not already used. In any case, if the port was already used, then it would give an error saying that the port is already in use, rather than attempt to start an instance?